# Rによるデータテーブルの作成について

Tags: r

行が1900、列が15のデータフレームを読み込み、パッケージによる分析のためにTableもしくはmatrixへ変換しようと試みました。ですが、要素が上限を超えることから、エラーが生じます。

```
Data_table <-  as.table(data)

Error in as.table.default(data) :  table に強制変換できません
2^31 個の要素を超えるテーブルを作成しようとしています 
attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements
```

分析に用いる関係上、上限を超えないようにデータを分割して扱うことはできません。何か解決方法があればご教示ください。

Comment: 一旦、データフレームをリストに変換するという対応が考えられます(`as.table(unlist(data))`)。上手く行くかどうか分かりませんが、試してみて下さい。

Comment: ご提案頂いた方法で対応できました。感謝申し上げます。